# General guidelines for creating a custom loss/cost function?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-models, optimization, loss-functions

I have a 3 class problem for which the outcomes can be described below using a confusion matrix.  1 are the outcomes I want the model to maximize and 5 are the outcomes I want the model to minimize.  In other words, if the model is going to predict correctly, squares with 1 are more important than squares with 2. If the model is going to predict incorrectly, it better not predict square 5 incorrectly.

[image]

Are there any general guidelines I should follow or things to keep in mind for creating my own cost function or can I just play around until I make one that fits what I'm looking for.  I would imagine one requirement is differentiable.  Anything else?

Comment: What should be differentiable? Your cases and outcomes seem to be discrete.  You could just multiply the cases by the values in the table and add the results up

Comment: The cost function/loss function that you are looking to minimize or maximize - I thought would need to be differentiable.   So there really aren't many rules of thumbs for creating your own cost function?  It's more trial/error based.  One can treat the form of the cost function as an additional hyperparameter that needs to be tweaked?

Comment: Related: ["Evaluating classification results when importance of correct classification varies with class"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/429831).